# react ref value is empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component with an uncontrolled input element like below:

```
class TestComponent {

onAddTypeClicked = el => {
    console.log(el);
    console.log(el.value);
};


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                name="asset_types"
                ref={el => this.assetTypesAdd = el}
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={e => this.onAddTypeClicked(this.assetTypesAdd)}
            />   
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now when I type some value in input field and click button, the input is getting printed correctly but it's value is empty. It works fine if I use document.getElementById approach though. Can anyone point if I'm doing anything wrong, please?

Comment: Would you try to pass `.current`? so `this.onAddTypeClicked(this.assetTypesAdd.current);`

Comment: current is valid if we create ref using React.createRef() but in my case I'm using callback pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code is working correctly and the value of accessible in `this.assetTypesAdd.value` and its printed value is the same. I'm not sure where you are getting an empty value for the input.

```js
// Example class component
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  onAddTypeClicked = el => {
      console.log(el.value);
      this.forceUpdate();
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                name="asset_types"
                ref={el => this.assetTypesAdd = el}
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                onClick={e => this.onAddTypeClicked(this.assetTypesAdd)}
            >
                Click me
            </button>
            {this.assetTypesAdd && 
                <div>Value of input: {this.assetTypesAdd.value}</div>}
            
        </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just realized that there was a mistake in my code.